# FS.mkdir relative path

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I want to use winston to create a logfile, but I'm running into issues when I try to create a directory,

If I use an absolutepath, something like

`fs.mkdirSync("/absolute/path/to/directory");`

The directory is created just fine,

but if I want the directory to be created in the current working directory of the application

`fs.mkdirSync("winstonLogs");`

Proceeds without error, but no directory is created. How do I create the directory in the current project directory so that wherever my application is deployed it can create its logfiles?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fs.mkdir(__dirname + '/newDir');`

You can also try process.cwd

fs.realpath(path[, options], callback)# History path | options | encoding default = 'utf8' callback Asynchronous realpath(3). The callback gets two arguments (err, resolvedPath). May use process.cwd to resolve relative paths.

See here for more information about using process.cwd:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: using that command gives me an error saying "no such file or directory"

Comment: FYI, `__dirname` is not necessarily the same as current working directory.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes I'm realizing that, but so how do I create this file (but not if it already exists?)

Comment: Check out my updated answer. Hopefully it will help.

Comment: @ChrisSharp where do I get the "path" object to feed to `fs.realpath`?

Comment: Pass it process.cwd

Comment: @ChrisSharp process.cwd() seems to get me my literal active meteor local build, not the correct directory.

Comment: Are you in some sort of weird callback? Why not catch the __dirname in a variable outside of it and then pass that variable to the callback?

Comment: Also, try __filename and then strip the filename off of the end of the returned string. If you're getting that you can't find any of these then it's probably because you're out of scope. In that case, you'll need to capture the location before you go out of scope and pass it wherever you're going.